# Vim syntax highlighting disappeared for text files (.txt)

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

My to-do list is a plain text .txt file that I load in Vim. In .txt files Vim has always coloured hash marks (#) and the text following them on the same line, which I use to mark out urgent to-do items. The other day this highlighting disappeared and I can't for the life of me see how to restore it. I've turned on all the syntax and filetype commands I can find. Should I have a text.vim or txt.vim syntax file that I might've deleted without realising? It feels like there should be a simple solution, but I can't find anything approaching a simple solution from googling round - I'm certainly not going to reinstall, write a custom syntax file, use a complex script, etc., I just want the default behaviour back.

Comment: What platform are you running on? Windows, Mac OS or Linux (which distribution)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that your Vim is broken.  Try putting a hash mark (#) at the beginning of the **first line** in the file.  When Vim sees this, it sets the filetype to **conf** (for a configuration file).  As far as I know, Vim does not syntax color vanilla text files.

Comment: The straight forward way to force a filetype is a modeline, e.g. `# vim: set filetype=conf :`. Also, asciidoc comes with syntax highlighting for `.txt` files (but no, hashed lines are not colored specially).

Comment: Wow! erichui and honk, that did the trick - I set filetype to Generic config, saved and quit and all is well again in todo-land. Thank you!

Comment: For me, this did not work. I had to use modelines (see [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/1068427/260809)). However, thanks for leading me to `conf` which, unlinke `config`, does not highlight numbers and some keywords.

Comment: `#` in the beginning text file is not working(i.e syntax highlight as `conf`) in gvim anymore after I updated to `8.0.3`

Answer (score 2):

Vim supports modelines. To force coloring the file as `conf` ([erichui's answer](https://superuser.com/a/216701/260809)), put the following line at the end or beginning of your file:

```
# vim: syntax=conf
```

This sets vim's internal variable `syntax` to `conf`.

Note: you could also set `filetype` (`ft`) instead of `syntax`.

Comment: Put it into the `vimrc`to enable this for all `txt` files: `echo "autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt set syntax=conf" >> ~/.vimrc`